# InAppSettingsKit multi value not showing options

Tags: iphone, settings, multivalue, inappsettingskit

I have just managed to create my settings.bundle and set up a selection of different settings. However when I run my app and view the settings via InAppSettingsKit, the multi value options aren't displayed. I see the title and I can select it, then when it should display the options it just shows n empty cells (except for the tick).

The odd thing is that if I go into the Apple Settings app and check out the multi value settings they all show up as expected. Does anyone have any idea whats going on?

This is the code I'm using in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IASKAppSettingsViewController.h"

@interface myViewController : UIViewController <IASKSettingsDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
{
    IASKAppSettingsViewController *appSettingsViewController;
}
```

And in the .m file I have the following:

```
- (IBAction)optionsButtonSelected:(id)sender
{
    appSettingsViewController = [[[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IASKAppSettingsView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    appSettingsViewController.delegate = self;
    appSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;
    UINavigationController *aNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appSettingsViewController] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
}
```

Below is a screenshot of a portion of my settings bundle (showing on of the problematic multi-value options):

[image]

And here is a screenshot showing what is displayed in the in app settings section when I click on Style:

[image]

Comment: Can you post (a minimal test case of) the content of your settings bundle?

Comment: @OrtwinGentz I have added in a couple of screenshots to provide more information.

Comment: Do you have a localization file? I noticed you wrote "Display Style" in the plist but got "Style" on screen.

Comment: I have not created a localisation file, the only thing that I have is a folder called 'en.lproj' which was generated in the settings.bundle. I have looked everywhere in the plist to work out why its coming up with Style instead of Display Style but I can't find any possible reference to it. It's got me pretty bewildered to be honest.

Comment: Does the problem still occur when putting your plist into the IASK sample app? If yes, please post it for download so I can check.

Comment: I just tried it in the IASK sample app and it worked ok. One thing I noticed is that it displayed 'Display Style' instead of 'Style' though.

Comment: I have just managed to fix the issue. I ended up resetting the iPhone simulator. Thank you for you help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by resetting the iPhone simulator. It seems it was getting confused between some old and new plist settings for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

sorry it won't allow me to vote up. I also fixed a similar problem by quitting the simulator and running the app again (also try to delete the app?).